# How to sum the value of two functions?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have two function creating the present value from the future value:

```
function calculate_zins1() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var zins1 = document.getElementById("zinsValue").value;
    var zins1_1 = parseInt(1) / (Math.pow(1 + (zins1/100),1)) ;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * zins1_1;
    result.value = myResult;
}

function calculate_zins2() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box2').value; 
     var zins1 = document.getElementById("zinsValue").value;
    var zins1_1 = parseInt(1) / (Math.pow(1 + (zins1/100),2)) ;
    var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');   
    var myResult = myBox1 * zins1_1;
    result2.value = myResult;
}
```

Now I want to add result + result2.

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call that functions ?

Comment: document.getElementById('result').value + document.getElementById('result2').value (??)

Comment: @Julo0sS that would result in string concatenation, not addition.

Comment: Return the results from those functions and just add them. Or just grab the values from the DOM and add them after you've called these functions. I'd return values from these functions TBH, rather than setting the values in the DOM directly. It will be more flexible that way.

Comment: var results = parseInt(calculate_zins1()) + parseInt(calculate_zins2());

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the function return the values you want.

```
function calculate_zins1() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var zins1 = document.getElementById("zinsValue").value;
    var zins1_1 = parseInt(1) / (Math.pow(1 + (zins1/100),1)) ;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * zins1_1;
    result.value = myResult;
    return myResult;
}
function calculate_zins2() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box2').value; 
     var zins1 = document.getElementById("zinsValue").value;
    var zins1_1 = parseInt(1) / (Math.pow(1 + (zins1/100),2)) ;
    var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');   
    var myResult = myBox1 * zins1_1;
    result2.value = myResult;
    return myResult;
}

sum = calculate_zins1() + calculate_zins2()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');

var sum = Number(result.value) + Number(result2.value);
```

I think the suggestion of simply making the functions return the calculated value is insufficient. They should either return the value **or** set it as the `value` property of the input element, they shouldn't do both. A function doing two different things is, especially when it's side effects, bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just return the value and do: 
`var sum = calculate_zins1() + calculate_zins2()?`

Or you could maybe pass as reference, to do that make the result an object:

```
var results = { result1 : null, result2 : null}
calculate_zins1(results) {
    ...
    results.result1 = result.value;
}

calculate_zins2(results) {
    ...
    results.result2 = result2.value;
}

calculate_sum() {
    return sum = results.result1 + results.result2;
}
```

Comment: You answered a question with a question? =]

Comment: The functions SHOULD return a value in this instance. He clearly wants the values to set in two DOM elements AND he also wants to add the values. Therefore, he should return values from the functions. He doesn't have to, but it would be a better design.

Comment: That's why I suggested the him to return the values :)

Comment: I wouldn't say he clearly wants to do anything. He didn't say that

Comment: @AtheistP3ace it's not exactly a question, but more of a suggestion

Comment: This is a comment not answer

Comment: Ah ok, it was the question mark at the end that threw me off lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result, result2;

function calculate_zins1() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var zins1 = document.getElementById("zinsValue").value;
    var zins1_1 = parseInt(1) / (Math.pow(1 + (zins1/100),1)) ;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * zins1_1;
    result.value = myResult;
}

function calculate_zins2() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box2').value; 
     var zins1 = document.getElementById("zinsValue").value;
    var zins1_1 = parseInt(1) / (Math.pow(1 + (zins1/100),2)) ;
    var result2 = document.getElementById('result2');   
    var myResult = myBox1 * zins1_1;
    result2.value = myResult;
}

var sum = result.value + result2.value;
```